# Fetching all remote branches into a bare Git repository

Tags: git, github

I set up a Github post-receive hook, which runs a script on my web server whenever a push is made to my Github repository.

When the script runs, I want it to keep a local bare clone of the repository synchronized with my Github repository. To do this, I have it run this command:

```
git fetch origin && git reset --soft refs/remotes/origin/master
```

Then, if from my workstation I push to master on Github, everything works just fine. However, if I push to another remote branch, the changes are not reflected in my server's local bare repository.

I'm assuming there's some way to have the script fetch *all* of the remote branches, but I don't know how to do this. I know newer versions of git have a --all option for fetch/pull, but I'm using git version 1.6.3.3, which doesn't seem to have this option.

Does anyone know how I can get my script to fetch all remote branches?

Thanks!

Comment: "Upgrade to the latest git" seems like a fairly straight-forward solution, surely?

Comment: I suppose I could do that. I'm just trying to avoid messing with Ubuntu's packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shell script perhaps?

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in `git remote show`; do
    git fetch $i;
done;
```

Note: Small terminology error in your question: The `--all` option of `git fetch|pull` fetches all "remotes", not "remote branches".

Comment: Git 1.6.3 has `git remote update`, which is a builtin version of this. `git fetch --all` is preferred in the versions that have it because the *git remote* command is supposed to be for maintaining the configuration of remotes, not performing actions on them (`update` is an anomaly in this regard, thus the preference for `git fetch --all`).

Comment: git fetch origin '*:*' is looking like the best

Answer (score 40):

`git fetch origin '*:*'` worked for me.

Comment: This! You don't need an loops.

Comment: If you just want branches, use `refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*`. If you want just branches and tags (exclude things like github pulls), also add `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd provide my own solution while I'm at it. I accepted Ramkumar's though, as it was the inspiration for this. The difference is I don't want to fetch from all remotes, but rather each remote branch in "origin"...

```
#!/bin/bash
REMOTE_BRANCHES=$(git branch -r | awk -F'/' '{print $2}')
for i in $REMOTE_BRANCHES; do
    git fetch origin $i
done
```

DISCLAIMER: haven't really implemented this yet, but it should be close.

Comment: You really should not try to parse the output of *git branch*. The lower-level “plumbing” command *git for-each-ref* is designed for scripted iteration over ref names. I am surprised that a plain `git fetch origin` does not update all of your “origin/*” remote-tracking branches. Iterated uses of `git fetch origin branch-name` will probably not do what you want either. When you give *git fetch* a refspec without a colon (the last arg is the refspec) it only stores the fetched commits in the special FETCH_HEAD ref (it will not update your remote-tracking branches).

Comment: I see your point. I didn't know about the git for-each-ref command. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch origin *:*` worked for me on Windows.

git version 2.29.2.windows.3